# Seeking Norwegian waterlines and water bodies shapefile?

Tags: data, norway

I am searching for a shapefile containing waterbodies and waterlines (rivers, etc.) in Norway, ideally at scale 1:50 000.

I have found a great resource of topographic map here: https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/metadata/kartverket/n50-kartdata/ea192681-d039-42ec-b1bc-f3ce04c189ac but my downloaded data contain a raster of topo map and vectors, which do not contain river lines neither river bodies.
 [image]

I have also found a WMS service for topo data: https://openwms.statkart.no/skwms1/wms.topo4.graatone? which contain the rivers ("*Elver*", "*Vannkontur*"), but I can not modify the style of those data neither simply overlay it on my map.

I have downloaded multiple datasets such as http://www.diva-gis.org/datadown but those show just the most important rivers, not the smaller rivers at the 1:50000 scale.

**How can I access the river and water bodies data from Norway?**

My study area is near Østfold. Unfortunately, I am not a Norwegian speaker.

Comment: And by the way, you may ask this question on [Open Data SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have you already investigated the most known sources for such data, e.g. [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=Norway#map=5/65.443/17.925), [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata), [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/), or [European Environment Agency (EEA)](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2/gis-files/norway-shapefile) or just search on Google something like `"Norway rivers shapefile"`.

Comment: @Taras, of course I have already investigated those sources and did not find the river network at sufficient detail. Only the big rivers are listed in those websites.

Comment: I would search here https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no, maybe this dataset: [Vannforekomster](https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/metadata/norges-vassdrags-og-energidirektorat/vannforekomster/b203e422-5270-4efc-93a5-2073725c43ef)

Comment: awesome, thank you @BERA, this is exactly what I needed :) Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Kartkatalogen](https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/search). Water is called Vann i norwegian, maybe this dataset could be what you are looking for: [Vannforekomster](https://kartkatalog.geonorge.no/metadata/norges-vassdrags-og-energidirektorat/vannforekomster/b203e422-5270-4efc-93a5-2073725c43ef):

> Dataset showing water quality in watercourses

[image]